# Changing Variable in forms onclick

Tags: javascript, html

Okay guys... I've built an eCommerce site for my wife, who sells eLiquids..  The problem I am having has to do with the e-junkie cart I'm using...  I am trying to change the hidden value of "amount" when a bottle size is selected from a dropdown box..  I would like the "amount" value to change depending on each size selection... nothing i've tried has worked..  here's the snippet

```
<form action="https://www.e-junkie.com/ecom/fgb.php?c=cart&cl=1&ejc=2" target="ej_ejc" method="POST">


<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="12.00"/>
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1"/>

Bottle Size: 
<input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Size"/>
<select name="os1" >
<option value="15">15 ML</option><option value="30">30 ML</option>   
<option value="50">50 ML</option>
</select><br>



<input type="hidden" name="shipping2" value="0.5">
<input type="hidden" name="handling" value="0.5">
<input type="hidden" name="tax" value="0.50"/>
<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="http://www.e-junkie.com/"/>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"/>

<input type="image" src="https://www.e-junkie.com/ej/ej_add_to_cart.gif" border="0" onClick="javascript:return EJEJC_lc(this.parentNode);">
```

I've tried using onClick with the on1, but it doesn't change the amount value...

I'm trying to change the hidden "amount" value to either 12 20 or 30 depending on which size is selected...  any help would be great

Comment: are you using a JS framework here? `javascript:return EJEJC_lc(this.parentNode);` never seen EJEJC code so can't really help but `onclick=""` should not contain javascript: really

Comment: right... but you can refer it to a function... such as onClick="myfunction()"

Comment: yeah you can even have the return it's how we used to do blocking on links, E.G `<a href="test.html" onclick="return false;"` but to be able to help we need to know what framework your using as in jQuery what your wanting is really easy but i have never seen anything with `EJEJC`

Answer (score 1):

You can change the value of the `amount` field by assigning an `onchange` function to the `os1` select box.  Here is an example javascript function:

```
    function changePrice() {
      var size = document.getElementById('os1').value;
      var price = 12;

      switch(size){
        case '15':
          price = 12;
          break;
        case '30':
          price = 20;
          break;
        case '50':
          price = 30;
          break;
        }
      document.getElementById('amount').value = price;
     }
```

You would then also need to give you amount input an ID:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="12.00" id="amount" />
```

And give the select box an ID, and assign it an `onclick` event:

```
    <select name="os1" id="os1" onchange="changePrice();">
      <option value="15">15 ML</option>
      <option value="30">30 ML</option>   
      <option value="50">50 ML</option>
    </select>
```

**However** - I **don't recommend doing this** if you are dealing with payments. It would be too easy for someone to change the amount value themselves in their browser and submit any amount they want to the payment process.  At the very least you need to validate the bottle size and amount to pay on your server before processing the payment to prevent this kind of attack.

Comment: I have to say i highly agree with the "***however***" you should never do what we have both shown you to do for a public facing system. it should be the sizes have items in a database table and the value is an item id and when the add to basket is clicked you should search get the price from the database table

Comment: I understand your concern, however, we are just a home business.. All orders will be reviewed personally before we make them.. though a more secure alternative would be appreciated.  I will do some research regarding the database tables

Answer (score 1):

This is not nice and raw JavaScript but it should work for you.

Change

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="12.00"/>
```

to

```
<input type="hidden" id="amount" name="amount" value="12.00"/>
```

And change:

```
<select name="os1" >
<option value="15">15 ML</option><option value="30">30 ML</option>   
<option value="50">50 ML</option>
</select><br>
```

to

```
<select id="os1" name="os1" >
<option value="15">15 ML</option><option value="30">30 ML</option>   
<option value="50">50 ML</option>
</select><br>
```

And finally change:

```
<input type="image" src="https://www.e-junkie.com/ej/ej_add_to_cart.gif" border="0" onClick="javascript:return EJEJC_lc(this.parentNode);">
```

To

```
<input type="image" src="https://www.e-junkie.com/ej/ej_add_to_cart.gif" border="0" onClick="return changeCost();">
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeCost(){
  var amountElm = document.getElementById("amount");
  var selectList = document.getElementById("os1");
  var selectedValue = selectList .options[selectList .selectedIndex].value;
  if(selectedValue == "15"){
    amountElm.value "12.00";
  }else if(selectedValue == "30"){
    amountElm.value "20.00";
  }else if(selectedValue == "50"){
    amountElm.value "30.00";
  }
  return true;
}
</script>
```